# Error on reverse-proxy nodejs app with ngnix

Tags: node.js, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm following a book Building Bots with node.js

I have a server with node.js node red and ngnix on line

I clone simple serve code from github

https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/NodeJS-EmptySiteTemplate

When i tried to proxy in nginx I have this error:

**Cannot GET /bottest**

this is default directives for ngnix

---

```
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#







server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;
    #server_name **************;
    #return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name *****************;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-*************.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;



    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
                }

      location /nodered {
      if ($scheme = http) {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
        proxy_pass http://**************:1880;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          }
    location /hello1 {
        proxy_pass ***************:1880;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /bottest {
        proxy_pass **********:8181;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }           


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }

#}
```

---

this is my server.js code:

---

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('This is my Facebook Messenger Bot - Whos Off Bot
Server');
});
// for facebook verification
app.get('/webhook', function (req, res) {
if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] ===
'whosoffbot_verify_token') {
res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
} else {
res.status(403).send('Invalid verify token');
}
});
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
var events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
var event = events[i];
if (event.message && event.message.text) {
if (event.message.text.indexOf('hi') > -1) {
sendMessageWithInitialOptions(event.sender.id);
}
}
}
res.sendStatus(200);
});
function sendMessageWithInitialOptions(recipientId) {
messageData = {
'attachment': {
'type': 'template',
'payload': {
'template_type': 'button',
'text': 'Pl. Select your options',
'buttons': [{
'type': 'postback',
'title': 'Schedule a Meetting',
'payload': 'SCHEDULE A MEETING'
}, {
'type': 'postback',
'title': 'Whos Off When',
'payload': 'WHOS OFF WHEN',
}, {
'type': 'postback',
'title': 'My Schedule',
'payload': 'MY SCHEDULE'
}]
}
}
};
sendMessage(recipientId, messageData);
};
function sendMessage(recipientId, message) {
request({
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
qs: { access_token: 'PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN' },
method: 'POST',
json: {
recipient: { id: recipientId },
message: message,
}
}, function (error, response, body) {
if (error) {
console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
} else if (response.body.error) {
console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
}
});
};
app.listen((process.env.PORT || 8181));
```

---

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2014/08/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://dev.nodejs.com/;
    location / {
       rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       proxy_redirect http://localhost:3000 http://dev.nodejs.com/;
       proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Please refer this link